# Gantt chart name suggestion - Length or Width

Tags: data-structures, charts, naming-conventions, naming, gantt-chart

I'm not sure if this is the right `Stack Exchange` site to ask good name for bars in Gantt Chart.

[image: Gantt Chart]

**Data Structure**

```
public class GanttChartData
{
    public ICollection<GanttBarData> BarCollection { get; set; }
}

public class GanttBarData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Length { get; set; }
}
```

**Question** Should I use `Length` or `Width` to represent length of a bar? I know it would be horizontal bar always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length) states:

> In geometric measurements, length is the longest dimension of an
>   object.

Hence your choice of BarLength is correct as the horizontal length is (almost!) always going to be the longest dimension of a bar in your chart.